# React, creating optimal production bundles with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

Today I dove into the internals of Webpack and I managed to use a lot of its usefull features (via Webpack loaders) such as `CSS` modules and the Babel transpiler. I want to use this to make a React app (without `create-react-app`).

Here is my config file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js',
    },


    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        query: {
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Because I now have a single entry point my whole bundle gets converted into a single `JS` file. However, as my react app grows it would probably be better to split the bundle up in multiple chunks so they can be downloaded faster (this is right terminology right?).

### Question:

1. What are aspects I need to take into consideration when splitting an application up into mutliple chuncks?
2. How does one go about splitting an application into mutliple chunks? Do I just enter multiple entry points (If this is the case what are tactical entry points then?)?

Comment: Hey @WillemvanderVeen! are you sure you need to split your bundle into multiple chunks? Because most of the time you do not need to. I think the first question you need to answer is `Do I really need to split my bundle?` If you really need to split up you bundle then you can create a bundle per root :)

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to split up the bundle into multiple chunks. But I saw it at other places. For example an Angular application is a single HTML file with multiple bundles

Comment: Yes it is a common thing to have a multiple bundle. But why do you want to do so? Does your app is very slow to load?  If you really need or want to, IMO the best way to do it is to have a bundle per root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have multiple entry points.

You can chunk based on

- **routes**
- **max size** of a chunk
- having separate chunk for **external dependencies**
- using **dynamic imports** for modules wherever it makes sense

If you are not sure about what params to use, use the default values with webpack's splitchunk plugin (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

You can then try out you own customizations to figure out what works best for your app.

Comment: How do we chunk based on routes in React @Nishant ? Is there any link/blog I could follow?